# Is it possible to distribute the documentation along with XCFramework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework, docc

I have develop a framework and I am able to generate documentation with **DocC**. When I include the .framework in the client app, I am able to see documentation when Option-Click on a method or property. However when I distribute the framework as XCFramework and included in the client app, Xcode doesn't show any documentation when Option-Click on a method or property.
When I examine the XCFramework, there is a file called "arm64-apple-ios.swiftdoc" that appears to have the documentation. But it is not accessible anywhere.

I still could not found any resource on the internet yet. If it is possible to carry documentation along with XCFramework please share how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.